# How to serialize object without curly braces in .Net Core

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core

I am using NewtonJson for serializing object. I want to serlize a object which has two properties one is normal string and the second property is dictionary of some items.

I am expecting a result something like this:

```
"Company": {
            "Id": "1393",
            "emp1": {
                "email": "test1@example.com",
                "firstName": "test1",
                "lastName": "test1",
                "title": "Mr"
            },
            "emp2": {
                "email": "test2@example.com",
                "firstName": "test2",
                "lastName": "test2",
                "title": "Ms"
            }
        }
```

but I am getting output like below:

```
"Company": {
            "Id": "1393",
            "employees": {
                "emp1": {
                    "email": "test1@example.com",
                    "firstName": "test1",
                    "lastName": "test1",
                    "title": "Mr"
                 },
                 "emp2": {
                    "email": "test2@example.com",
                    "firstName": "test2",
                    "lastName": "test2",
                    "title": "Ms"
              }
            }
        }
```

Here is my Code:

```
public string GetCompany(Dictionary<string, Employee> employees)
        {
            var company = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Id = "1393",
                employees
            });

            return company;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating the anonymous object, your adding another property named `employees`.

Why not just append `Id` to the dictionary?

e.g.

```
var employeesCopy = employees
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (object)kvp.Value);

employeesCopy["Id"] = "1393";

var company = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeesCopy);
```

This makes a copy of `employees` and adds a new key `"Id"` before serialising.

Comment: its giving an error: ``` cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Employee>' to 'int' ```

Comment: @davidjames Yeah, I overlooked the generic variance. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Poco (Plain Old C# Object). Make sure to add `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute.

```
public class Poco
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Employees { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And then serialize it

```
var employees = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { Path.GetRandomFileName(), new Employee() },
    { Path.GetRandomFileName(), new Employee() }
};

var company = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Poco { Id = "1393", Employees = employees });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not clear what is your goal. If you just need a json string , you can try this code

```
public string GetCompany(string id, Dictionary<string, Employee> employees)
{
    var e = JObject.FromObject(employees);
    e.AddFirst(new JProperty( "Id", id));
    return e.ToString();
}
```

but probably you need something bigger, so maybe it makes some sense to create a JObject in order to add it to another part  of you data. In the end you can serialize it calling ToString() function

```
public JObject GetCompany(string id, Dictionary<string, Employee> employees)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(employees);
    jo.AddFirst(new JProperty( "Id", id));
    return jo;
}
```